# How to port QNetworkAccessManager to WebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt

I know that Qt WebEngine does not interact with QNetworkAccessManager. But how do you port this code from 5.5 to 5.7 in order for it to work?

```
QNetworkAccessManager *p =  getView()->page()->networkAccessManager();
```

networkAccessManager is highlited and error says "class QWebEnginePage has no member networkAccessManager"

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question -- "Qt WebEngine does not interact with QNetworkAccessManager." So what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe I want to know if there's any other way to send network requests like these, since QNetwork and WebEngine don't interact with each other?

Comment: When you port, why do you need to get the pointer to QNetworkAccessManager? QNetworkAccessManager should disappear from code, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution, to share Cookies with QWebEngine and QNetworkAccesManager by using QWebEngineCookieStore. Subclass QNetworkCookieJar:

```
class CookieWebEngine : public QNetworkCookieJar
{
.....
protected:
    // Reimplement this functions to work with your _cookies list;
    bool insertCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie);
    bool deleteCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie);
    bool updateCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie);
    bool validateCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie, const QUrl &url) const;
private:
    // Save Chromium Cookies
    QWebEngineCookieStore *_store;
    // Save available cookies
    QList<QNetworkCookie> _cookies;
}
```

Now, lets implement a function to load/save cookies in a file:

```
// Load Chromium Cookies
void CookieWebEngine::loadStore() {
    // Save cookies profile shared
    QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::ForcePersistentCookies);
    _store = WebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->cookieStore();
    connect(_store, &QWebEngineCookieStore::cookieAdded, this, &CookieWebEngine::handleCookieAdded);
    _store->loadAllCookies();
}
// Load/Save cookies in arraylist in a file
void CookieWebEngine::load() {

    // load cookies and exceptions
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<QList<QNetworkCookie> >("QList<QNetworkCookie>");
    const QString location = cookiesDirectory() + COOKIES_FILE;
    QSettings cookieSettings(location, QSettings::IniFormat);
    _cookies = qvariant_cast<QList<QNetworkCookie> >(cookieSettings.value(QLatin1String("cookies")));
    setAllCookies(_cookies);
    // Now user iterate and add it to chromium
    for (auto cookie : _cookies) {
       _store->setCookie(cookie);
    }
    cookieSettings.sync();
}

void CookieWebEngine::save()
{
    QString directory = cookiesDirectory();
    if (!QFile::exists(directory)) {
        QDir dir;
        dir.mkpath(directory);
    }
    const QString location = directory + COOKIES_FILE;
    QSettings cookieSettings(location, QSettings::IniFormat);
    cookieSettings.setValue(QLatin1String("cookies"), QVariant::fromValue<QList<QNetworkCookie>>(_cookies));
    cookieSettings.sync();
}
```

Now, just connect and handle cookies loaded from the webview:

```
void CookieWebEngine::handleCookieAdded(const QNetworkCookie &cookie)
{
    if (insertCookie(cookie)) {
        qDebug() << "Handle cookie " << cookie;
    }
}
```

Its working well for me. Now, i use chromium to sign in. After, i save my session cookie in the customized cookiejar and I use it in my customized QNetworkAccesManager.

**You should update all your network manager. You could i subclassing QWebEnginePage and add an slot to update your QNetworkAccesManager and the funcition which will return your NetworkAccesManager**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:

> Qt WebEngine does not interact with QNetworkAccessManager
>
> Some classes of Qt Network like QAuthenticator were reused for their
> interface but, unlike Qt WebKit, Qt WebEngine has its own HTTP
> implementation and cannot go through a QNetworkAccessManager. The
> signals and methods of QNetworkAccessManager that are still supported
> were moved to the QWebEnginePage class.

**Qt WebKit:**

```
QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
QWebPage page;
page.setNetworkAccessManager(&qnam);
connect(&qnam, SIGNAL (authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*)), this, SLOT (authenticate(QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*)));
```

**Qt WebEngine:**

```
QWebEnginePage page;
connect(&page, SIGNAL (authenticationRequired(QUrl, QAuthenticator*)), this, SLOT (authenticate(QUrl, QAuthenticator*)));
```

Source: https://wiki.qt.io/Porting_from_QtWebKit_to_QtWebEngine

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to port it the way you describe, however it's possible to bring QtWebKit from 5.5.1 to 5.7.. it will require some 'fine-tuning' in compile options but it's not really difficult and works very stable including QML support.